# How to install MUMPS database in Windows 8.1?

Tags: mumps

I would like to install MUMPS database in Windows 8.1. I was trying to install but there is no exe file for MUMPS database. Can anyone give me a hand?. I downloaded a lot of files from this site https://sourceforge.net/projects/mumps/files/ but still don't know where to start.

Comment: Do you want to play with mumps related database? Have you tried free evaluation version of InterSystems Caché? You can download it here: download.intersystems.com . It is back compatible with almost any mumps database

Answer (score 0):

From the README for that project, you'll need to install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html):

```
NOTES on cygwin

For Windows, install the Cygwin environment at http://cygwin.com/install.html

Run cygwin terminal (on win7 or win8 run it as administrator).

Setup the Cygserver using /usr/bin/cygserver-config.

  edit /usr/include/cygwin/shm.h
     add near end
     #define SHM_R (IPC_R)
     #define SHM_W (IPC_W)

  edit /usr/include/cygwin/ipc.h
     move third last #endif 3 lines up
```

Once you have Cygwin setup, the mumps.exe file available to download at the link you provide should run.

That said, I would agree with Evgeny in recommending you try the free evaluation version of InterSystems [Caché](https://download.intersystems.com/download/login.csp). It is a far more accessible Mumps implementation for Windows and it has an extensive set of libraries for common functionality.